# devtools Error in read.dcf(path_desc) : Line starting 'This corresponds to ...' is malformed

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I've spent long enough on this problem that I thought I'd make a post about it.

Using `devtools` to develop R packages is really a must. 
I generated my new package with the usual command :

```
usethis::create_package(proj_path)
```

Then I started working on the contents. Editing the `DESCRIPTION` file, adding R code in the `R/` folder and documenting with Roxygen.

Once I had some basic things put down, I wanted to check my work by documenting/building the package so I ran

```
devtools::document(proj_path)
```

and got the following error

> Error in read.dcf(path_desc) : 
>     Line starting 'This corresponds to  ...' is malformed!

That's it, no info on what caused the error.

I never wrote anything even close to "This corresponds to" in my doc.
The closest thing to this error I found is [this issue](https://github.com/OHDSI/Achilles/issues/349) on github, which has the same type of `Error in read.dcf(` idea, but this did not help my case.

Comment: If you compile the documentation using roxygen2 directly, do you get any more information on what is happening?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I've just tried this, and I get the exact same error. (`roxygen2::roxygenise(proj_path)`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So the clue I missed is the `desc` part of the `Error in read.dcf(path_desc)`.
This alludes to the `DESCRIPTION` file of the package.

When I substituted the `DESCRIPTION` file for a brand new template one, the package compiled fine. My issue actually came from the description part of the file.

I forgot a tabulation when I inserted a new line.

```
Description: blabla
blabla
```

instead of

```
Description: blabla
   blabla
```

And that fixed it.